# How to comment out the current line?

Tags: coderush

Is there a way (shortcut) to quickly comment out the current code line in CodeRush?

I've just moved over from ReSharper which seemed more intuitive in this matter.

And yes - I know about the "/" shortcut that comments out a selection of code. I'm looking for something that will meet my requirement without the need to select a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you need to select the entire line including the leading whitespace to make the '/' shortcut work. See [this article](http://skorkin.com/2010/11/selection-quick-commentuncomment/) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a big limitation. Is there a way to quickly select the content of the current line?

Comment: CodeRush has a feature called Selection Increase, which increases the selection by logical blocks. Place the caret at the start of the code and press Num+ (the numeric Plus key) or Ctrl+W. This can also select entire methods, classes, try blocks, for loops, etc. It just depends where the caret is when you press the key.

Answer (score 2):

Built in VS Ctrl K Ctrl C does that job (and Ctrl K U to remove commenting)